# Why does this not add?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked other questions and have tried to fix this but I am really struggling with having my code print back the answer.

```
from tkinter import *



root = Tk()
label1 = Label(root, text="Number 1")
label2 = Label(root, text="Number 2")
labelplus = Label(root, text="+")

label1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
label2.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
labelplus.grid(row=2, column=1)


entry1_var= StringVar()
entry2_var= StringVar()

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable= entry1_var)
entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable= entry2_var)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)

first = (entry1_var.get()
second =(entry2_var.get()

def additionStuff(event):
    totalNumbers = (first + second)
    print(totalNumbers)

button1 = Button(root, text="Add Numbers")
button1.bind("<Button-1>", additionStuff)
button1.grid(row=4, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Why does my function now print back the answer?

Comment: because you are getting the value of the entry widget a millisecond after creating the widget, rather than after the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `StringVar.get` inside of `additionStuff`:

```
def additionStuff(event):
    first = entry1_var.get()
    second = entry2_var.get()
    totalNumbers = (float(first) + float(second))
    print(totalNumbers)
```

Otherwise you're getting the value of first and second before the user has had opportunity to enter anything.

Comment: You also need to convert `first` and `second` to `int` or `float`.

Comment: After I do that and type in 1 + 1 it returns 11. EDIT: fixed it to floats. Thank you